# Django ModelForm: Huge ForeignKey queryset leads to crash when loading form

Tags: django, django-forms

Basically, I have two models: User and Event. An event is always associated with one user.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    hashed_password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Event(models.Model):
    event_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And then I have the following form for Event.

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'user']
```

I can succesfully show this form in my template to create an event. I can also associate a user to a form successfully with Select field when the users number are still few.

Now the problem is, when I have 1M users in database, my browser crashes when loading the template. Any idea how to solve this one? I was thinking about using AJAX and then search user that matches the username, but I'd like to hear other better approaches. Thanks!

Comment: Who is filling out this form? Is it a user as you defined in your question?

Comment: cf Daniel's comment above. If the event is supposed to belong to the current user, the proper solution is to remove the user field from the form's field and add it "manually" (from the `request.user`).

Comment: Hi! No, the event does not belong to the current user. A user can fill any user to be associated with the event. @DanielH.